# Отображение разницы документов на веб-странице

Tags: python, веб-программирование, fastapi

Есть сервис для загрузки документов пользователя, который написан с использованием `FastApi`.
Мне необходимо при загрузке второго такого же документа отобразить изменения в нем.
Что-то типа `git diff` в веб-версии для документов.
Я не нашел каких-то библиотек на питоне при первом приближении.
Встает вопрос:
 Сталкивался ли кто-то с подобным и как вы это решали?
Будут полезны любые советы по поиску нужной информации в интернете.
 
Заранее спасибо всем, кто обратит внимание и ответит!
Типы документов для рассмотрения `diff`: `doc`, `docx`

Comment: Это зависит от формата документа, позволяет ли он вообще делать осмысленные диффы

Comment: @andreymal, рассматриваются стандартные форматы `doc`, `docx`. Спасибо за уточнение, сейчас поправлю вопрос

Comment: Только что нашел версию `Aspose` для питона. Попробую поюзать ее, отпишу что получится и скину рабочий пример как решение.

Comment: Нашел еще более простую библиотеку - `diff-match-patch`

Comment: Не уверен, что она умеет адекватно сравнивать doc/docx... ну или разве что вы предварительно преобразуете их в простой текст, теряя всё форматирование

Comment: Ну а для простого текста в питоне и встроенный [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html) есть (хотя он медленнее чем diff-match-patch)